# Antiderivative of $f\left( \xi \right) =\xi^{a}\left( b\xi ^c+K\right) ^d$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, hypergeometric-functions

I need to know the primitive function (Antiderivative) of this function:
$$f\left( \xi \right) =\xi^{a}\left( b\xi ^c+K\right) ^d$$
where

- $K$ is an integration constant,
- $d=-\frac{1}{2p}$ with $p<0$,
- $a=-c_{1}$ , $b=\frac{2pc_{2}}{2pc_{1}-1}$ , $c=1-2pc_{1}$ and the constants $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are:
  $$
  c_{1}=\left( \frac{1}{2n\left( 1-p\right) }+\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right) \quad  c_{2}=\frac{\alpha }{\left( 1-p\right) \left( 2n\right) ^{-2p+2}}\qquad n\in \mathbb{N}, \alpha<0
  $$

Please could you help me in finding how could I find the primitive of this function? Is there any particular technique concerning this types of functions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

Even with specific values of $n=1$, $p=-1$, $\alpha=-1$, and $K=1$, Mathematica can only provide the trivial expression in terms of the hypergeometric function. So, it is highly unlikely that more can be done here.

Here is the image of the corresponding Mathematica notebook:

[image]